# for await loop loses elements when iterating over a Mongoose QueryCursor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, async-await

In a nodeJs application I'm using a `for await` loop to iterate a Mongoose cursor inside an `async` function. Something like this:

```js
    let count = 0
    const movies = Movies.find({}).cursor();
    for await (const movie of movies) {
      count++
    }
    console.log(count);
```

This prints 311, which is correct.

The problem arises when I try to do an async operation inside the loop. Like this:

```js
    let count = 0
    const movies = Movies.find({}).cursor();
    for await (const movie of movies) {
      await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 10)); // <- any async operation
      count++
    }
    console.log(count);
```

This prints 296. Some documents have been lost.

I'm not sure if it is a Mongoose specific problem. I couldn't reproduce it with other async iterators so far.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Is there any pattern in the missing documents?

Comment: @abondoa I don't think so. I think the cursor ends prematurely for any reason and last documents are lost. No error is thrown.

Comment: I am wondering if this could be a timeout issue of the cursor. How does it behave when you use larger/smaller values in your `setTimeout`? In the example for `for await` on mongoose, theiy are not calling `.cursor` but using the result from `find` directly - does that change the behaviour? (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#streaming)